# How can i check the type and version (is it socks4 or socks5) of a random proxy server in python?

Tags: python, proxy, python-asyncio

i'm trying to create an asynchronous parser using asyncio and aiohttp_socks. The script collects a list of "IP:PORT" of different proxies.
How can i check the type of each proxy: is it http, socks4 or socks5? More precisely, I'm even interested in the ability to filter everything except socks5.